# Disable / Force Traffic through HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: ssl

To my understanding its not possible due to One being Secure the other not (Different Protocols) 
But i thought i would ask the question first just in case.

Website content has just a few static HTML pages, No need for a Cert IMO. 
But some Visitors accidentally visit the page via https.

I wanted to avoid the message about Invalid Cert and just re-direct them to Http. 
But in order to use a Re-Write engine, the Connection to HTTPS has to already be established. So regardless of the Re-write i would also get the Cert error.

Is it possible to configure this via iptable, or a configuration within Apache?

Comment: *"But some Visitors accidentally visit the page via https."* If the server isn't even listening on 443, how do you know this?

Comment: Chicken and egg, you cant do it without an established HTTPS session which requires a certificate.  Why not get a $10 one?

Comment: You can get valid SSL certificate *for free* at [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), [Start SSL](https://www.startssl.com/Support?v=1) or other. SSL can be configured using [Mozilla configurator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/). You can use HTTP/2 on Apache starting with 2.4.17, which is supported typically only over TLS by the most web browsers. HTTP/2 can improve the performance of you web site. Thus I don't recommend to make redirection from HTTPS to HTTP.